# Syntax Highlighting for Laravel Blade Template Engine in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, laravel, sublimetext

In Sublime Text 2, what steps do I need to take to get Syntax Highlighting for the Laravel Blade Template Engine to work?

As described in http://daylerees.com/2012/04/06/notable-blade-syntax-support-by-medalink/, I took https://github.com/Medalink/Laravel-Blade, unzipped it and copied the folder into Sublime's packages folder.

However, it doesn't seem to work (see screenshot), even if I set it manually using Tools\Command Palette...\Set Syntax: Blade

Is this only meant to work with particular Color Schemes (if so, which ones), or what am I missing? (I just started using Sublime Text today)

[image]

Comment: I used the same package for blade syntax highlighting, but installed it from the package control plugin. Take a look at http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control

Answer (score 22):

The easiest way to install plugins for Sublime Text 2 is through Package Control.

[To install Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control/installation):

> Installation is through the Sublime Text 2 console. This is accessed via the ctrl+` shortcut. Once open, paste the following command into the console:
>
> ```
> import urllib2,os; pf='Package Control.sublime-package'; ipp=sublime.installed_packages_path(); os.makedirs(ipp) if not os.path.exists(ipp) else None; urllib2.install_opener(urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.ProxyHandler())); open(os.path.join(ipp,pf),'wb').write(urllib2.urlopen('http://sublime.wbond.net/'+pf.replace(' ','%20')).read()); print 'Please restart Sublime Text to finish installation'
> This command creates the Installed Packages folder for you (if necessary), and then downloads the Package Control.sublime-package into it.
> ```

When you have Package Control installed all you need to do to install the Blade syntax highlighter is to:

1. Open the command palette and type "install package"
2. Press enter
3. Wait for a new palette to show up after it has fetched the package list
4. Type "blade syntax"
5. Press enter
6. Enjoy

Comment: At step 1 I'm typing `install package` and I get a *SyntaxError*.

Comment: @yannishristofakis I would have to guess that Package Control wasn't properly installed then. Try to install Package Control again and make sure you don't get any errors.

Comment: Or you can download it from here: [Source on github](https://github.com/Medalink/Laravel-Blade)

Answer (score 16):

For Sublime text 3 as well as sublime text 2

1. install Sublime Package Control (more help on: http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control/installation)
2. then restart sublime text (2/3)
   and press ---->  control (or command in mac) + shift + p
3. there search for package control: install package
4. wait for another interaction screen
5. search for Laravel Blade (and other packages if you want)

{
For video tutorials on this and other , subscrive this channel : https://www.youtube.com/channel/UChEv_j3fE4k2r7KcEApFDyQ
}

Comment: I've followed your tutorial and this link http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/pro-workflow-in-laravel-and-sublime-text/ (to create dog resource) and it didn't generate anything. I'm using windows and sublime text 2. I've already add php executable in path environment, assoc .php to php executable. Did I miss something?
Error detail:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\generate.py", line 59, in call_artisan
  File ".\subprocess.py", line 633, in __init__
  File ".\subprocess.py", line 842, in _execute_child
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Brother Please make sure you have installed the package first. First google about **how to install packages** on Sublime (2 / 3) . You will get the installer code [Here](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation#st3) .
All the best Bro \m/

Answer (score 3):

Also, once you have Package Control installed, you should also install the package 'DetectSyntax'. It will automatically detect the blade syntax so you don't have to manually set it for each file.

Comment: can't find it in the list:(

Comment: @Kreker The package name has changed from `DetectSyntax` to `ApplySyntax` See here: https://github.com/facelessuser/ApplySyntax

Comment: Thank you, I already had it installed but thought I didn't because it wasn't auto applied :)

Comment: Built-in option: 'View > Syntax > Open all with current extension as... > PHP Laravel Blade'.

Answer (score 0):

In case you installed the Laravel Blade Syntax Highlighter using Package control, that plugin, for some reason keeps throwing out errors.

Package Control: The package specified, laravel-blade, is not available

What I did is just Preference > Browse packages and then rename the folder into laravel-blade. Seems working with no pesky errors now. What I did is just gut feel. I did not even read anything in the files in the folder.

--
Edited: Go to Preference > Browse packages > Package Control.sublime-settings and remove the offending entry.

Comment: I think an update was pushed that changed a few things. Might need to uninstall it and make sure everything was deleted. Close and re-open ST2 and install again.

Comment: Actually, my gut feel was wrong. Although I did not take time pinpointing what the source of the problem was(leaning towards a rename of the package responsible of laravel highlighting), and my going to the Package Control.sublime-settings in wherever your OS is saving this file, was showing an entry for laravel-blade. All I needed to do was remove it from the JSON file. Voila, no errors, no need to reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

mine was stored in users folder, just do a folder search for "laravel-blade" and remove the entry from json config

Find: laravel-blade
Where: /Users/:username/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages